# Trying to expand data using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am an admitted novice with XSLT and am looking for some direction.  I have the follow (simplified) XML input data.  I want to take the underlying  data and apply it to AccountExternalSystemId or flatten it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<ns:CustomObject3WS_CustomObject3QueryPage_Output xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/customobject3/10/2004">
<ns:LastPage>true</ns:LastPage> 
<ListOfCustomObject3 xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3">
    <CustomObject3>
        <AccountExternalSystemId>A000008351</AccountExternalSystemId> 
        <ListOfAccount>
            <Account>
                <AccountId>AAXA-H72YN</AccountId> 
                <ExternalSystemId>100000000002795</ExternalSystemId> 
                <Name>CATERPILLAR INC [100000000002795]</Name> 
            </Account>
            <Account>
                <AccountId>ADOA-3BAK0F</AccountId> 
                <ExternalSystemId>A000008351</ExternalSystemId> 
                <Name>CATERPILLAR</Name> 
            </Account>
        </ListOfAccount>
    </CustomObject3>
    <CustomObject3>
        <AccountExternalSystemId>100000000001059</AccountExternalSystemId> 
        <ListOfAccount>
            <Account>
                <AccountId>AAXA-H0B7N</AccountId> 
                <ExternalSystemId>100000000001059</ExternalSystemId> 
                <Name>SERV SA [100000000001059]</Name> 
            </Account>
        </ListOfAccount>
    </CustomObject3>
</ListOfCustomObject3>
```

I am applying the following XSL to the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*:CustomObject3WS_CustomObject3QueryPage_Output"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*:CustomObject3WS_CustomObject3QueryPage_Output">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*:LastPage"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*:ListOfCustomObject3"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*:ListOfCustomObject3">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*:CustomObject3"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:CustomObject3">
        <xsl:variable select="*:AccountExternalSystemId" name="AccountExternalSystemId"/>
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*:ListOfAccount/*:Account">        
                <xsl:element name="AccountId" namespace="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3"><xsl:value-of select="substring(*:AccountId,1,15)"/></xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="AccountName" namespace="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3"><xsl:value-of select="substring(*:Name,1,255)"/></xsl:element>

                <xsl:element name="AccountExternalSystemId" namespace="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3"><xsl:value-of
                select="substring($AccountExternalSystemId,1,64)"/></xsl:element>

        </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and here is my result (you can see that CustomObject3 is not properly ended (as there should be 2) in the first example.  Not sure if my approach is the best way to accomplish what I need to do:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns:CustomObject3WS_CustomObject3QueryPage_Output>
    <ns:LastPage>true</ns:LastPage>
    <ListOfCustomObject3 xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3">
      <CustomObject3>
         <AccountId>AAXA-H72YN</AccountId>
         <AccountName>CATERPILLAR INC [100000000002795]</AccountName>
         <AccountExternalSystemId>A000008351</AccountExternalSystemId>
         <AccountId>ADOA-3BAK0F</AccountId>
         <AccountName>CATERPILLAR</AccountName>
         <AccountExternalSystemId>A000008351</AccountExternalSystemId>
      </CustomObject3>
      <CustomObject3>
         <AccountId>AAXA-H0B7N</AccountId>
         <AccountName>SERV SA [100000000001059]</AccountName>
         <AccountExternalSystemId>100000000001059</AccountExternalSystemId>
      </CustomObject3>
   </ListOfCustomObject3>
```

The desired output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:CustomObject3WS_CustomObject3QueryPage_Output>
<ns:LastPage>true</ns:LastPage>
<ListOfCustomObject3 xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3">
  <CustomObject3>
     <AccountId>AAXA-H72YN</AccountId>
     <AccountName>CATERPILLAR INC [100000000002795]</AccountName>
     <AccountExternalSystemId>A000008351</AccountExternalSystemId>
  </CustomObject3>
  <CustomObject3>
     <AccountId>ADOA-3BAK0F</AccountId>
     <AccountName>CATERPILLAR</AccountName>
     <AccountExternalSystemId>A000008351</AccountExternalSystemId>
  </CustomObject3>
  <CustomObject3>
     <AccountId>AAXA-H0B7N</AccountId>
     <AccountName>SERV SA [100000000001059]</AccountName>
     <AccountExternalSystemId>100000000001059</AccountExternalSystemId>
  </CustomObject3>
```

Comment: Please provide wanted output.

Comment: desired output added ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Remark** note that the output in your question presents a prefix (`ns:`) **not bound** to any namespace declaration.

Look at this direction:

- where `identity.xsl` is the well known [**Identity Transformation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e17557)
- default namespaces are handled in a simpler way
- produced output has the correct namespace declarations

[XSLT 2.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="CustomObject3">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ListOfAccount/Account"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Account">
        <CustomObject3>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="AccountId|Name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../AccountExternalSystemId"/>
        </CustomObject3>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <xsl:element name="Account{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives wanted output (with correct namespace declarations):

```
<ns:CustomObject3WS_CustomObject3QueryPage_Output xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/customobject3/10/2004">
   <ns:LastPage>true</ns:LastPage>
   <ListOfCustomObject3 xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/customObject3">
      <CustomObject3>
         <AccountId>AAXA-H72YN</AccountId>
         <AccountName>CATERPILLAR INC [100000000002795]</AccountName>
         <AccountExternalSystemId>A000008351</AccountExternalSystemId>
      </CustomObject3>
      <CustomObject3>
         <AccountId>ADOA-3BAK0F</AccountId>
         <AccountName>CATERPILLAR</AccountName>
         <AccountExternalSystemId>A000008351</AccountExternalSystemId>
      </CustomObject3>
      <CustomObject3>
         <AccountId>AAXA-H0B7N</AccountId>
         <AccountName>SERV SA [100000000001059]</AccountName>
         <AccountExternalSystemId>100000000001059</AccountExternalSystemId>
      </CustomObject3>
   </ListOfCustomObject3>
</ns:CustomObject3WS_CustomObject3QueryPage_Output>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and response.  I can see from my simplified input data where you made an assumption about linking AccountExternalSystemId with Account[ExternalSystemId] however this is not the way I need to associate.  At the AccountExternalSystemId level I will have many attributes.  I just need to be able to add the Account[AccountId] attribute for every Account[AccountId] to all the attributes at the AccountExternalSystemId level.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Adapted the initial answer to the wanted output. Check my answer now.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Really helps me to understand better.

Comment: @Adam welcome. Make sure to accept the answer if you think fulfills your question.